# How to balance two columns with two tables in revtex 4.2

Tags: tables, two-column, revtex, tikzmark

I am using revtex 4.2 as a basis for company documents (until I learn enough to write my own class). In a particular document, I have an appendix which has a couple tables in it, as well as some text. When I compile the document, the appendix, found on the second page of the example included below, displays in two columns, as intended, but has a ragged bottom. The left hand column is longer than the right column. If the text portion of the appendix content were split between the left and right columns (preferrably at the top of those columns), the bottoms of the tables could be made flush. How can I accomplish this? I do want to keep the two tables on the same page as the rest of the appendix text, and intend to copy and paste the whole appendix section into multiple documents that use the same template.

[image: Appendix A, page 2 from the sample code below.]

```
 \documentclass[
 aapm,
 showkeys,
 mph,
 amsmath,
 amssymb,
 nofootinbib,
 nobibnotes,
 %preprint,
 reprint,
 %draft,
 %final,
]{revtex4-2}





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%% Section Labeling Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Package Imports %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[]{longtable}
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ToDo Notes Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[obeyDraft]{todonotes}
\makeatletter
\if@todonotes@disabled
\newcommand{\hlfix}[2]{#1}
\else
\newcommand{\hlfix}[2]{\texthl{#1}\todo[
                                        color=yellow,
                                        size=\tiny,
                                        ]{#2}}
\fi
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Versioning Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{mVersion}
\setVersion{0.1}
\increaseBuild
\renewcommand{\version}{v\versionnumber \ifoptionfinal{}{(\thebuildcounter)}}
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%% Document Name and ID Setup %%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\DocTitle}{xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx-xxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx x 1111}
\newcommand{\DocDivision}{xxxxx}
\newcommand{\DocGroup}{xxx}
\newcommand{\DocType}{xx}
\newcommand{\DocNumber}{001}
\newcommand{\VersionString}{\DocType -\DocNumber -\version}
\newcommand{\DocExt}{.pdf}
\newcommand{\FileName}{xx\_xxxxxxxxx\_xxxxxx\_xxxx2263\_\version\DocExt}
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Draftmark Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newsavebox\wmbox
\savebox\wmbox{\tikz[
                     color=red,
                     opacity=0.15,
                     ]%
               \node[
                     rectangle,%
                     draw=white,%
                     ultra thick,%
                     scale=7.7,%
                     rotate=45,
                     ]{DRAFT\version};}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\put(.5in, -.85\paperheight){\ifoptionfinal{}{\usebox\wmbox}}}
%----------------------------------------------%

    
    
               

%----------------------------------------------% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Hyperlink setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
            final,
            colorlinks=true, 
            linkcolor=blue,
            filecolor=magenta,      
            urlcolor=cyan,
            citecolor=blue,
            pdftitle={\DocTitle},
            pdfauthor={xxxx x. xxxxxxxx},
            pdfinfo={document version={\versionnumber},
                     build number={\thebuildcounter}},
            }
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Classification Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\INTERNAL}{\fcolorbox{black}{gray!15}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY}}}%
\newcommand{\CONFIDENTIAL}{\fcolorbox{black}{red!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{CONFIDENTIAL}}}%
\newcommand{\SECRET}{\fcolorbox{black}{red!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{SECRET}}}%
\newcommand{\TOPSECRET}{\fcolorbox{black}{red}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{TOP SECRET}}}%
\newcommand{\ITARNF}{\fcolorbox{black}{red}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{ITAR-NOFORN}}}%
\newcommand{\UNCLASSIFIED}{\fcolorbox{black}{green!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{UNCLASSIFIED}}}
\newcommand{\UNRESTRICTED}{\fcolorbox{black}{green!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{UNRESTRICTED}}}
\newcommand{\classification}{\INTERNAL}
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Header/Footer Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\classification\\\FileName}
\lhead{\VersionString \ifoptionfinal{}{\ DRAFT}}
\rhead{\thepage$|$\pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{\classification}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Newpage Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\balancecolsandclearpage}{%
  \close@column@grid
  \clearpage
  \twocolumngrid
}
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------%





%----------------------------------------------%
%************** Begin Document ****************%
%----------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\title[]{\DocTitle}
%\thanks{Footnote to title of article.}

\author{x.x. xxxxxxxx}
\email{xxxxxxxx\_x@xxx.com}
\author{x. xxxxxx}
\email{xxxxxx@xxx.com}
\affiliation{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx%\\
%4554 xxxxxxxxx xx\\
%xxxxxx xxxxx, xx 11111\\
%xxxxxx xxxxxx
\end{minipage}
}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxx xxxxxxx, xxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx x 1111 xx x xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx. xxxxxxx xxx x 1111 xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxxx.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{xxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy} %required for header and footer to appear on first page
\lipsum[1-6]
\balancecolsandclearpage

\appendix
\section{xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx (xxx) xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx 11 xxx \S11}\label{ap:etw}
\FloatBarrier 
xxxxxxxxxx: 11 xxx \S 11.111-11, \S\S 1111.111-1111.111.

xxx \emph{xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxxxx} xxxx x \emph{xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxxx xxxx xx xxxxx xx 1,111 xxx, xxxx xxx \emph{xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxx `xxxxx' xxxxxx xx xxxxx \ref{tab:etw}, xxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx `xxx' xxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.

xxx \emph{xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxxxx} xxxx x \emph{xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxxxxxx xxxx 1,111 xxx., xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xx 1,111 xxx. 

xxx xxxxx xxxx 1994 xxx xxxxx \emph{xxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxx} xxx xxxxxxx xx xxx xxxx 0 xxxxxxxxx xx 11 xxx \S 11.111–1, xxxx xxx \emph{xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxx `xxxxx' xxxxxx xx xxxxx \ref{tab:etw}, xxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx `xxx' xxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.

xxx xxxxx \ref{tab:68def} xxx xxxxxxxxxxx.
\flushbottom

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{\label{tab:68def}xxxxxxxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S11 xxx xxx xx xxxxxxxx \ref{ap:etw}}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.25\linewidth}  p{0.7\linewidth}}
xxxx & xxxxxxx\\ \hline
xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxx xxxx.\\
xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx & xxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx, xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx, xxxx x xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx.\\
xxxx & xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xx x xxxxxx xxxxxxx.\\
xxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx & xxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx 1111 xxx xxxx.\\
xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxxx &  x xxxxxxxxx xxx xx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx 11 xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxx. \\
xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx &  xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx 1,111 xxxxxx xxxx xx xxxx xxxxx xxx x xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xx 1,111 xxxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxx x xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xx 11 xxxxxx xxxx xx xxxx, xxxxx xx: (1) xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xx xx x xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxx x xxxxxxx, xx (1) xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxx xxx x xxxxxxxx xx xxxx xxxx 11 xxxxxxx, xx (1) xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxx-xxxxxx xx xxx-xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxx. \\
xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxx 111 xxxxxx.\\
xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxx'x xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx, xxx xxxxxx xx xxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx, xxx xxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S 11.111-11; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}



\begin{table}[h]
\caption{\label{tab:etw}xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S 11.111-11, xxx xxx xx xxxxxxxx \ref{ap:etw}.}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{cc}

xxxxx & xxx\\ \hline
Up to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
1111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
%\end{longtable}
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\FloatBarrier 

\balancecolsandclearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a `tikzpicture` to fit the two tables on the Appendix page.

To simplify the tikz template code, the two tables and the two captions have been defined as new commands.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[
aapm,
showkeys,
mph,
amsmath,
amssymb,
nofootinbib,
nobibnotes,
%preprint,
reprint,
%draft,
%final,
]{revtex4-2}


%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%% Section Labeling Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}
%----------------------------------------------%
    
%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Package Imports %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[]{longtable}

%*****************************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tabularx}% table width
\usepackage{capt-of} % for caption of

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} % amrk the origin
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   
%----------------------------------------------%

 %\usepackage{showframe} % show the margins

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ToDo Notes Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[obeyDraft]{todonotes}
\makeatletter
\if@todonotes@disabled
\newcommand{\hlfix}[2]{#1}
\else
\newcommand{\hlfix}[2]{\texthl{#1}\todo[
    color=yellow,
    size=\tiny,
    ]{#2}}
\fi
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Versioning Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{mVersion}
\setVersion{0.1}
\increaseBuild
\renewcommand{\version}{v\versionnumber \ifoptionfinal{}{(\thebuildcounter)}}
%----------------------------------------------%
        
%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%% Document Name and ID Setup %%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\DocTitle}{xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx-xxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx x 1111}
\newcommand{\DocDivision}{xxxxx}
\newcommand{\DocGroup}{xxx}
\newcommand{\DocType}{xx}
\newcommand{\DocNumber}{001}
\newcommand{\VersionString}{\DocType -\DocNumber -\version}
\newcommand{\DocExt}{.pdf}
\newcommand{\FileName}{xx\_xxxxxxxxx\_xxxxxx\_xxxx2263\_\version\DocExt}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Draftmark Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newsavebox\wmbox
\savebox\wmbox{\tikz[
    color=red,
    opacity=0.15,
    ]%
    \node[
    rectangle,%
    draw=white,%
    ultra thick,%
    scale=7.7,%
    rotate=45,
    ]{DRAFT\version};}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\put(.5in, -.85\paperheight){\ifoptionfinal{}{\usebox\wmbox}}}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Hyperlink setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    final,
    colorlinks=true, 
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdftitle={\DocTitle},
    pdfauthor={xxxx x. xxxxxxxx},
    pdfinfo={document version={\versionnumber},
        build number={\thebuildcounter}},
}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Classification Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\INTERNAL}{\fcolorbox{black}{gray!15}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY}}}%
\newcommand{\CONFIDENTIAL}{\fcolorbox{black}{red!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{CONFIDENTIAL}}}%
\newcommand{\SECRET}{\fcolorbox{black}{red!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{SECRET}}}%
\newcommand{\TOPSECRET}{\fcolorbox{black}{red}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{TOP SECRET}}}%
\newcommand{\ITARNF}{\fcolorbox{black}{red}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{ITAR-NOFORN}}}%
\newcommand{\UNCLASSIFIED}{\fcolorbox{black}{green!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{UNCLASSIFIED}}}
\newcommand{\UNRESTRICTED}{\fcolorbox{black}{green!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{UNRESTRICTED}}}
\newcommand{\classification}{\INTERNAL}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Header/Footer Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\classification\\\FileName}
\lhead{\VersionString \ifoptionfinal{}{\ DRAFT}}
\rhead{\thepage$|$\pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{\classification}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}
%----------------------------------------------%


%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Newpage Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\balancecolsandclearpage}{%
    \close@column@grid
    \clearpage
    \twocolumngrid
}
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------%

\newcommand{\AppTabi}{% first table <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{ruledtabular}
      \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{>{\hsize=.4\hsize}X X}
        xxxx & xxxxxxx\\ \hline
        xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxx xxxx.\\
        xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx & xxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx, xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx, xxxx x xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx.\\
        xxxx & xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xx x xxxxxx xxxxxxx.\\
        xxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx & xxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx 1111 xxx xxxx.\\
        xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxxx &  x xxxxxxxxx xxx xx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx 11 xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxx. \\
        xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx &  xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx 1,111 xxxxxx xxxx xx xxxx xxxxx xxx x xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xx 1,111 xxxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxx x xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xx 11 xxxxxx xxxx xx xxxx, xxxxx xx: (1) xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xx xx x xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxx x xxxxxxx, xx (1) xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxx xxx x xxxxxxxx xx xxxx xxxx 11 xxxxxxx, xx (1) xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxx-xxxxxx xx xxx-xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxx. \\
        xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxx 111 xxxxxx.\\
        xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxx'x xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx, xxx xxxxxx xx xxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx, xxx xxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S 11.111-11; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx.\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{ruledtabular}      
}

\newcommand{\Capi}{% caption of the first table <<<<<<<<<<<<
\label{tab:68def}xxxxxxxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S11 xxx xxx xx xxxxxxxx \ref{ap:etw}
}

\newcommand{\AppTabii}{% second table <<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{X  >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
        xxxxx & xxx\\ \hline
        Up to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
        1111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
        11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
        11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
        11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
        11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
        11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
        11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
        11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
        11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\      
    \end{tabularx}
\end{ruledtabular}      
}

\newcommand{\Capii}{% caption of the second table <<<<<<<
    \label{tab:etw}xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S 11.111-11, xxx xxx xx xxxxxxxx \ref{ap:etw}.
}


%----------------------------------------------%
%************** Begin Document ****************%
%----------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \title[]{\DocTitle}
    %\thanks{Footnote to title of article.}
    
    \author{x.x. xxxxxxxx}
    \email{xxxxxxxx\_x@xxx.com}
    \author{x. xxxxxx}
    \email{xxxxxx@xxx.com}
    \affiliation{%
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
            xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx%\\
            %4554 xxxxxxxxx xx\\
            %xxxxxx xxxxx, xx 11111\\
            %xxxxxx xxxxxx
        \end{minipage}
    }
    
    \date{\today}
    
    \begin{abstract}
        xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxx xxxxxxx, xxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx x 1111 xx x xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx. xxxxxxx xxx x 1111 xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxxx.
    \end{abstract}
    
    \keywords{xxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{fancy} %required for header and footer to appear on first page
    \lipsum[1-6]
    \balancecolsandclearpage
    
    \appendix
    \section{xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx (xxx) xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx 11 xxx \S11}\label{ap:etw}

    xxxxxxxxxx: 11 xxx \S 11.111-11, \S\S 1111.111-1111.111.
    
    xxx \emph{xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxxxx} xxxx x \emph{xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxxx xxxx xx xxxxx xx 1,111 xxx, xxxx xxx \emph{xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxx `xxxxx' xxxxxx xx xxxxx \ref{tab:etw}, xxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx `xxx' xxxxxx xx xxx 
    
    xxx xxxxx xxxx 1994 xxx xxxxx \emph{xxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxx} xxx xxxxxxx xx xxx xxxx 0 xxxxxxxxx xx 11 xxx \S 11.111–1, xxxx xxx \emph{xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxx `xxxxx' xxxxxx xx xxxxx \ref{tab:etw}, xxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx `xxx' xxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.

    xxx xxxxx \ref{tab:68def} xxx xxxxxxxxxxx. End of two columns

\noindent\tikzmark{e}% mark added <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % \draw[red] ( $ (pic cs:e) +(0mm,0mm) $ ) circle[radius=5pt]; % SHOW the origin (for debug)
    \node (Origin) at ( $ (pic cs:e) +(-0.5\linewidth-\columnsep,0.5\baselineskip) $) {};
    \node (tab1)[below=of Origin, text width=\linewidth] {\AppTabi};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,above=\belowcaptionskip of tab1,text width=\linewidth,yshift=-2mm]{\captionof{table}{\Capi}};
    \node [right=of tab1,xshift=-8mm,yshift=1mm, text width=\linewidth] (tab2)  {\AppTabii};    
    \node[inner sep=0pt,above=\belowcaptionskip of tab2,text width=\linewidth]  {\captionof{table}{\Capii}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question. (minor changes to the table definitions, basic solution the same)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[
aapm,
showkeys,
mph,
amsmath,
amssymb,
nofootinbib,
nobibnotes,
%preprint,
reprint,
%draft,
%final,
]{revtex4-2}


%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%% Section Labeling Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Package Imports %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[]{longtable}

%*****************************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tabularx}% table width
\usepackage{capt-of} % for caption of

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} % amrk the origin
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   
%----------------------------------------------%

%\usepackage{showframe} % show the margins

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ToDo Notes Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[obeyDraft]{todonotes}
\makeatletter
\if@todonotes@disabled
\newcommand{\hlfix}[2]{#1}
\else
\newcommand{\hlfix}[2]{\texthl{#1}\todo[
    color=yellow,
    size=\tiny,
    ]{#2}}
\fi
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Versioning Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{mVersion}
\setVersion{0.1}
\increaseBuild
\renewcommand{\version}{v\versionnumber \ifoptionfinal{}{(\thebuildcounter)}}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%% Document Name and ID Setup %%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\DocTitle}{xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx-xxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx x 1111}
\newcommand{\DocDivision}{xxxxx}
\newcommand{\DocGroup}{xxx}
\newcommand{\DocType}{xx}
\newcommand{\DocNumber}{001}
\newcommand{\VersionString}{\DocType -\DocNumber -\version}
\newcommand{\DocExt}{.pdf}
\newcommand{\FileName}{xx\_xxxxxxxxx\_xxxxxx\_xxxx2263\_\version\DocExt}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Draftmark Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newsavebox\wmbox
\savebox\wmbox{\tikz[
    color=red,
    opacity=0.15,
    ]%
    \node[
    rectangle,%
    draw=white,%
    ultra thick,%
    scale=7.7,%
    rotate=45,
    ]{DRAFT\version};}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\put(.5in, -.85\paperheight){\ifoptionfinal{}{\usebox\wmbox}}}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Hyperlink setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    final,
    colorlinks=true, 
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdftitle={\DocTitle},
    pdfauthor={xxxx x. xxxxxxxx},
    pdfinfo={document version={\versionnumber},
        build number={\thebuildcounter}},
}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Classification Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\INTERNAL}{\fcolorbox{black}{gray!15}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY}}}%
\newcommand{\CONFIDENTIAL}{\fcolorbox{black}{red!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{CONFIDENTIAL}}}%
\newcommand{\SECRET}{\fcolorbox{black}{red!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{SECRET}}}%
\newcommand{\TOPSECRET}{\fcolorbox{black}{red}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{TOP SECRET}}}%
\newcommand{\ITARNF}{\fcolorbox{black}{red}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{ITAR-NOFORN}}}%
\newcommand{\UNCLASSIFIED}{\fcolorbox{black}{green!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{UNCLASSIFIED}}}
\newcommand{\UNRESTRICTED}{\fcolorbox{black}{green!25}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2px][c]{UNRESTRICTED}}}
\newcommand{\classification}{\INTERNAL}
%----------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Header/Footer Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\classification\\\FileName}
\lhead{\VersionString \ifoptionfinal{}{\ DRAFT}}
\rhead{\thepage$|$\pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{\classification}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}
%----------------------------------------------%


%----------------------------------------------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Newpage Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\balancecolsandclearpage}{%
    \close@column@grid
    \clearpage
    \twocolumngrid
}
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------%

\newcommand{\AppTabi}{% first table <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{ruledtabular}\small
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize}X >{\hsize=.65\hsize}X}
            xxxx & xxxxxxx\\ \hline
            xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxx xxxx.\\
            xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx & xxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx, xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx, xxxx x xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx.\\
            xxxx & xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xx x xxxxxx xxxxxxx.\\
            xxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx & xxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx 1111 xxx xxxx.\\
            xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxxx &  x xxxxxxxxx xxx xx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx 11 xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxx. \\
            xxxxx-xxxx xxxxx &  xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xx 1,111 xxxxxx xxxx xx xxxx xxxxx xxx x xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xx 1,111 xxxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxx x xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xx 11 xxxxxx xxxx xx xxxx, xxxxx xx: (1) xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xx xx x xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxx x xxxxxxx, xx (1) xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxx xxx x xxxxxxxx xx xxxx xxxx 11 xxxxxxx, xx (1) xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxx-xxxxxx xx xxx-xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxx. \\
            xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxx 111 xxxxxx.\\
            xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxx'x xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx, xxx xxxxxx xx xxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx, xxx xxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S 11.111-11; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx.\\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{ruledtabular}      
}

\newcommand{\Capi}{% caption of the first table <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \label{tab:68def}xxxxxxxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S11 xxx xxx xx xxxxxxxx \ref{ap:etw}
}

\newcommand{\AppTabii}{% second table <<<<<<<<<<
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{ruledtabular}\small
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{>{\hsize=0.3\hsize}Y  >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}Y}
            xxxxx & xxx\\ \hline
            Up to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 1111 & 1,111 \\
            1111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
            11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
            11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
            11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
            11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
            11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
            11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
            11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\
            11111 to 11111 & 11,111 \\      
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{ruledtabular}      
}

\newcommand{\Capii}{% caption of the second table <<<<<<<
    \label{tab:etw}xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx 11 xxx \S 11.111-11, xxx xxx xx xxxxxxxx \ref{ap:etw}.
}


%----------------------------------------------%
%************** Begin Document ****************%
%----------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \title[]{\DocTitle}
    %\thanks{Footnote to title of article.}
    
    \author{x.x. xxxxxxxx}
    \email{xxxxxxxx\_x@xxx.com}
    \author{x. xxxxxx}
    \email{xxxxxx@xxx.com}
    \affiliation{%
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
            xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx%\\
            %4554 xxxxxxxxx xx\\
            %xxxxxx xxxxx, xx 11111\\
            %xxxxxx xxxxxx
        \end{minipage}
    }
    
    \date{\today}
    
    \begin{abstract}
        xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxx xxxxxxx, xxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx x 1111 xx x xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx. xxxxxxx xxx x 1111 xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxxx.
    \end{abstract}
    
    \keywords{xxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{fancy} %required for header and footer to appear on first page
    \lipsum[1-6]
    \balancecolsandclearpage
    
    \appendix
    \section{xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx (xxx) xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx 11 xxx \S11}\label{ap:etw}
    
    xxxxxxxxxx: 11 xxx \S 11.111-11, \S\S 1111.111-1111.111.
    
    xxx \emph{xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxxxx} xxxx x \emph{xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxxx xxxx xx xxxxx xx 1,111 xxx, xxxx xxx \emph{xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxx `xxxxx' xxxxxx xx xxxxx \ref{tab:etw}, xxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx `xxx' xxxxxx xx xxx 
    
    xxx xxxxx xxxx 1994 xxx xxxxx \emph{xxxxx xxxxx-xxxx xxxxxx} xxx xxxxxxx xx xxx xxxx 0 xxxxxxxxx xx 11 xxx \S 11.111–1, xxxx xxx \emph{xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx} xx xxx `xxxxx' xxxxxx xx xxxxx \ref{tab:etw}, xxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx `xxx' xxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.
    
    xxx xxxxx \ref{tab:68def} xxx xxxxxxxxxxx. End of two columns
    
    \noindent\tikzmark{e}% mark added <<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
         %\draw[red] ( $ (pic cs:e) +(0mm,0mm) $ ) circle[radius=5pt]; % SHOW the origin (for debug)
        \node (Origin) at ( $ (pic cs:e) +(-0.5\linewidth-\columnsep,0.5\baselineskip) $) {};
        \node (tab1)[below=of Origin, text width=\columnwidth] {\AppTabi};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,above=\belowcaptionskip of tab1,text width=\columnwidth,yshift=-1mm]{\captionof{table}{\Capi}};
        \node [right=of tab1, text width=\columnwidth ,xshift=-6mm,yshift=-6mm,] (tab2)  {\AppTabii};    
        \node[inner sep=0pt,above=\belowcaptionskip of tab2,text width=\columnwidth]  {\captionof{table}{\Capii}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it seems to result in inconsistent text sizing. Is there a way to ensure that the text in the tables stay as they should?